# Get industry and interest of 1st Degree Connections via Linkedin API

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am building a PHP site where the users login with their Linkedin account and be able to see the interests of each of their 1st degree connection:

```
$search_response = $linkedin->search("?facet=network,F");
```

With the code above I was able to pull some of their 1st degree contacts. The data returned only consists of first names, last names, headlines and pictures however. I want to be able to get their industries, specialities and interests as well.

I tried to look for a solution in the documentation but couldn't find anything. I'm a newbie at this so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the implementation of the `search()` method this is a bit of a guess, but basically you would use the [field selector](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/field-selectors) syntax to specify the [profile fields](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields) (and the associated data) you want returned.

Something along the lines of:

```
$search_response = $linkedin->search(":(id,first-name,last-name,headline,specialties,interests,industry,picture-url)?facet=network,F");
```